# Combining xlsx file with visual studio project into exe

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio, exe

I have made a project in visual studio that uses a `xlsx` database file called `DataBase.xlsx` and few more folder of images that i use their path to upload images into the UI.

All of these files are at my bin\debug folder and it works awesome when running in visual studio.

However, i want to publish it and make it `.exe` file. When i build it into the Release category it takes only the `.cs` file and it gets stuck when calling the `.xlsx` file because it dont know what that file is.

How can i build a visual studio project that uses more files as database?

Thank you

Comment: It sounds like you want to embed the XLSX file *in* your executable, but that's not going to work well if you need to modify it. Instead, set the build action for your file to `Content` and then when you publish your project it will include the file in the same directory as your executable.

Comment: If possible supply the XLSX with the EXE like @mason told. If not, you can embed the XLSX in the EXE using a Resource file (.Resx), I let you check this. You will probably have to write the actual XLSX on hard drive (which should not be a problem) before to be able to manipulate it from your software.

Comment: I wont need to change the xlsx file. it will be used only to read data from it (in case it helps in some way =])

Comment: @ben Do a little research for how to embed a file into an exe in .NET.